# upload_archive() operation in boto3 for glacier

Tags: python-3.4, boto3

Does the upload_archive() operation in boto3 for glacier automatically use multi-part upload when the data to be uploaded is larger than 100MB?

I believe this is the case in boto2 (see @lenrok258's answer in [Boto Glacier - Upload file larger than 4 GB using multipart upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127095/boto-glacier-upload-file-larger-than-4-gb-using-multipart-upload))

I have tried different ways to view the source code for the upload_archive() operation in boto3 for glacier, but I haven't been able to find it using inspect or ipython. If anyone happens to know how to do this and is willing to share it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike boto2, boto3 does not automatically use multi-part upload.

From a comment from a member of the boto project on [an issue on the boto3 Github](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1146):

> ... boto3 does not have the ability to automatically handle
>   multipart uploads to Glacier. That would be a feature request. There
>   are some features that exist in boto2 that have not been implemented
>   in boto3.

You'll have to implement it yourself using the [initiate_multipart_upload](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/glacier.html#Glacier.Client.initiate_multipart_upload) functionality.

Or, as another commenter on the issue suggests instead:

> The optimal usage pattern for interacting with Glacier is generally 
>   to upload to S3 and use S3 lifecycle policies to transition the 
>   object to Glacier.